# Escaping items in an array (Python)

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sanitization

```
>>> array = ['hello', 'world']
>>> result = map(lambda item: `item`, array)
>>> result
["'hello'", "'world'"]
```

or

```
>>> result = [`item` for item in array]
>>> result
["'hello'", "'world'"]
```

For sql I need everything escaped with ticks.

The result I am looking for is

```
["`hello`", "`world`"]
```

I'm not doing this to avoid SQL injection, im doing this to avoid errors on SQL reserved words

Comment: Side-note: `map(lambda item: \`item\`, array)` is a deprecated and slower way to spell `map(repr, array)`. Backticks are just a syntactic way to get the `repr` of an item, and it's deprecated (removed in Python 3).

Comment: In any event, doing this safely (to avoid SQL injection attacks) is harder than just adding backticks to the string. Use whatever parameterized query syntax your SQL library supports; you will *always* get manual escaping wrong, and parameterized queries can be more efficient to boot, so use them.

Comment: If you're already building queries, why not use a proper query builder: https://www.sqlalchemy.org

Answer (score 1):

Use the newest `f`-strings:

```
array = ['hello', 'world']
result = [f'`{item}`' for item in array]

print(result)
# ['`hello`', '`world`']
```

Or `format`:

```
result = ['`{}`'.format(item) for item in array]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get it, but is this what you are looking for:

```
array = ['hello', 'world']
['`' + s + '`' for s in array]

Out[51]: ['`hello`', '`word`']
```

or equivalently:

```
list(map(lambda x: '`{}`'.format(x), array))
Out[53]: ['`hello`', '`word`']
```

Comment: `lambda x: '\`{}\`'.format(x)` is a slow way to spell `'\`{}\`'.format`; I know people love `lambda`s, but methods and functions are first class objects, you can just use them directly. `map(lambda x: '\`{}\`'.format(x), array)` could become `map('\`{}\`'.format, array)`